# How to set connection timeout with OkHttp

Tags: java, timeout, okhttp

I am developing app using OkHttp library and my trouble is I cannot find how to set connection timeout and socket timeout.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: The answer you selected is no longer valid. Maybe you should edit question to specify version of okhttp.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

As of **OkHttp3** you can do this through the [Builder](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-3.0.0/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java#L386) like so

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

You can also view the recipe [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/ConfigureTimeouts.java).

For older versions, you simply have to do this

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Be aware that value set in `setReadTimeout` is the one used in `setSoTimeout` on the `Socket` internally in the `OkHttp` [`Connection`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.4.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Connection.java#L300) class.

Not setting any timeout on the `OkHttpClient` is the equivalent of setting a value of `0` on `setConnectTimeout` or `setReadTimeout` and will result in no timeout at all.  Description can be found [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.4.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java#L247).

As mentioned by @marceloquinta in the comments `setWriteTimeout` can also be set.

As of version `2.5.0` read / write / connect timeout values are set to 10 seconds by default as mentioned by @ChristerNordvik.  This can be seen [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.5.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java#L190).

Comment: Is there a way to set those timeout different for each request (each request has the same static client)?

Comment: You can set specific timeout for each request : Here some information :
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: @MiguelLavigne If no timeout was set , is there a default timeout or no timeout at all ?

Comment: @EviatarS I've updated the answer with that information.  Good luck!

Comment: Dont forget the WRITE timeout: client.setWriteTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: @MiguelLavigne Just FYI, OkHttp changed in 2.5.0 to have a default timeout of 10 sec.

Comment: @What if `client.call(...)` itself time's out.  It stops my entire loop.  If the call times out, I need it to break and continue the loop.

Comment: Outdated Answer

Comment: @MiguelLavigne, there are default timeouts. 10 seconds for connecting and 10 seconds for reading. See the docs: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html#callTimeoutMillis--

Answer (score 154):

For okhttp3 this has changed a bit.

Now you set up the times using the builder, and not setters, like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```

More info can be found in their wiki:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/b3dcb9b1871325248fba917458658628c44ce8a3/docs/recipes.md#timeouts-kt-java

Comment: I reuse same "client", how to set per request? (Because some requests are more important than others.)

Answer (score 12):

For Retrofit `retrofit:2.0.0-beta4` the code goes as follows:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(logging)
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.yourapp.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 9):

For `Retrofit 2.0.0-beta1` or `beta2`, the code goes as follows:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

client.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
client.setWriteTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.yourapp.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding in gradle file and **sync project**:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Adding in Java class:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder;


Builder b = new Builder();
b.readTimeout(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
b.writeTimeout(600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// set other properties

OkHttpClient client = b.build();
```

Answer (score 7):

**OkHttp** Version:`3.11.0` or higher

From okhttp source code:

```
/**
 * Sets the default connect timeout for new connections. A value of 0 means no timeout,
 * otherwise values must be between 1 and {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE} when converted to
 * milliseconds.
 *
 * <p>The connectTimeout is applied when connecting a TCP socket to the target host.
 * The default value is 10 seconds.
 */
public Builder connectTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
    connectTimeout = checkDuration("timeout", timeout, unit);
    return this;
}
```

`unit` can be any value of below

```
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS
TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
TimeUnit.SECONDS
TimeUnit.MINUTES
TimeUnit.HOURS
TimeUnit.DAYS
```

example code

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)/*timeout: 5 seconds*/
    .build();

String url = "https://www.google.com";
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Updated

I have add new API to **OkHttp** from version `3.12.0`, you can set timeout like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)) // timeout: 5 seconds
    .build();
```

**NOTE:** This requires API `26+` so if you support older versions of Android, continue to use `(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

Answer (score 6):

It's changed now. Replace `.Builder()` with `.newBuilder()`

As of **okhttp:3.9.0** the code goes as follows:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
    .newBuilder()
    .connectTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

Comment: This is incorrect. What newBuilder() does is creating a new instance of OkHttpClient  that shares the same connection pool, thread pools, and base configuration as the original client, but which can be otherwise configured differently. It is meant to reuse the same shared resources while serving a different specific purpose. For instance, if you need a different client with a shorter timeout.

In the end, there's no reason to change new OkHttpClient.Builder() for new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().

Source: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
//New Request
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(logging)
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false) <-- not necessary but useful!
    .build();
```

Source: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3553

Comment: it depends on the usecase " <-- not necessary but useful!"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize the configuration then use the below methodology of creating OKhttpclient first and then add builder on top of it.

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

// Copy to customize OkHttp for this request.
OkHttpClient client1 = client.newBuilder()
    .readTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();
try (Response response = client1.newCall(request).execute()) {
    System.out.println("Response 1 succeeded: " + response);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Response 1 failed: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a call timeout to cover the entire cycle from resolving DNS, connecting, writing the request body, server processing, and reading the response body.

```
val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().callTimeout(CALL_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()
```