# Kotlin - How to set connection timeout with OkHttp Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, timeout, okhttp, kotlin-android-extensions

I see this `

> [How to set connection timeout with OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953819/how-to-set-connection-timeout-with-okhttp/39383456)

But this link for Java(Android) Language.I want to use **kotlin** Language...
`
I am using OkHttp library

```
 val client = OkHttpClient()

 val time = client.connectTimeoutMillis() // it's get only methood but i looking for method for set Timeout
```

and my trouble is I cannot find how to **set** connection timeout and socket timeout For Kotlin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set connection timeout with OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953819/how-to-set-connection-timeout-with-okhttp)

Comment: You should do the same thing. Kotlin has little difference in this aspect comparing to Java. Just call `OkHttp.Builder`, configure it with needed timeouts and build an object. The code must be the same as for Java.

Comment: I khow..but this link for java(android).i want for android kotlin language

Comment: val test = OkHttp.Builder.....but test not method for set timeout

Comment: The language doesn't matter in this case. Just do `val client = OkHttp.Builder().connectionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()`

Comment: @andrei_zaitcev I don't know to use (Builder). thank you for help. your solution works for me

Comment: The problem with the question you linked is not that it is Java and you are using Kotlin but that the accepted answer is for OkHttp2 - but [other answers are for OkHttp3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762061/3755692)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `Builder` is required, there are no setters available. With [OkHttp 3.9.1](https://github.com/square/okhttp) you can do this:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much different than the accepted answer, but it seems it is best to return the same OkHttpClient to avoid memory leaks.

```
sealed class ClientBuilder {

    companion object {
        val plainClient: OkHttpClient by lazy {
             OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
        }
    }

    fun client() : OkHttpClient {
        return plainClient
    }
}
```