# How to set the whole timeout in OkHttpClient?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I tried to google find the related issue but no luck. I know how to set the connectionTimeout, readTimeout, writeTimeout but I want to set the whole timeout for these value because sometimes the value between these three are vary.

The similar is this one

[How to set connection timeout with OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953819/how-to-set-connection-timeout-with-okhttp)

But the one I want is something like that

```
builder.allTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any method that can set timeout for all as you can check it in documentation.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/

Further, I couldn't find a reason that why do you want to achieve this.

Try some below workaround that may solve your problem.

Initialise a const value

```
final int ALL_TIMEOUT = 30;

new OkHttpClient().newBuilder() 
    .readTimeout(ALL_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(ALL_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    .writeTimeout(ALL_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

OR

Make a wrapper that will initialise your builder and just pass a value for all timeouts and wrapper will initialise all timeouts itself and give you the builder object.

Answer (score 0):

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder() 
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had an implementation of SSL and I was creating custom OkHttpClient that was overriding my further implementation. I was setting there timeout and I was not able to change it. I have forgot about it and spend a lot of time to find the problem which was simple. Take a look at your own code and check if you have no other implementation of OkHttpClient which is overriding your timeouts.