# How to set connection timeout in okhttp3?

Tags: android, okhttp

How can I set time out in this code?

```
okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient();
okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .get()
    .build();
Call call = client.newCall(request);
call.enqueue(callback);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set connection timeout with OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953819/how-to-set-connection-timeout-with-okhttp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
```

Comment: I have edited my answer ;). Just opened my AndroidStudio and tried it. This should be it. Sorry I had written the initial answer from the top of my head. My bad!

Comment: Edited again. Just the `new` keyword was missing (was using Kotlin - hence there was no need for new). I really hope it will work right now. If not please tell me I really want to help you to get this done

Comment: Oh and you might have to write `okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()` (just depends on your import)

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!