# How to fix errors with timeout on okhttp client

Tags: java, android

I have already set a connection with API, everything seems to be working but I need to set a timeout for data to show. I have checked the answers from before here on StackOverflow, but none of the methods seem to fit. Do you know any way of how to set the timeout right?

I tried several codes from these answers ([How to set connection timeout with OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953819/how-to-set-connection-timeout-with-okhttp)) and there was always some issues with it. At this point, I have an error that says that it cannot resolve the method setReadConnection

`OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();`

I was just hoping that this would help me to finally show the data in the app. Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that you looking for?

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            //default timeout for not annotated requests
            .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```